# Salesforce Marketing Cloud - MobilePush - Cordova Plugin Android integration Issue

Tags: android, sfdcmobilesdk-android, mobilepush-android, cordova

I am trying to integrate Salesforce Marketing Cloud SDK with Android using Cordova Plugin. But I am getting gradle build issues. Below is the Error:

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.salesforce.marketingcloud:marketingcloudsdk:6.3.+.

This is the repository it is trying to connect (No Proxy issues):
maven { url "http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/repository" }

Comment: Post your Gradle build + settings

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed now. I used secured url in repositories rather than unsecured.

https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/repository